# Enable/Disable Drawable DIVs

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsbin.com/AyaDOVO/3/edit

I'm been experimenting with this drawable div function, and I'm having trouble isolating it so it is only called when the draw button is clicked and disabled when the start button is clicked.

Here's my JQuery/Javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var drawable = false;

  $('.div-tool').click(function() {
    drawable = true;
  });

  $('.select-tool').click(function() {
    drawable = false;
  });

  function draw_a_box( e ) {

    var pageX = e.pageX,
        pageY = e.pageY,
        dpLast = dp.find('.drawnBox.last'),
        dpLast_data = dpLast.data();

    $('.drawnBox').css({
      'position': 'absolute',
      'z-index': '1',
      'border': '1px solid #222',
      'background': '#e1e1e1',
      'opacity': '0.5'
    });

    if ( e.type === 'mousemove' ) {

      // If ".drawnBox.last" doesn't exist, create it.
      if ( dpLast.length < 1 ) {
        $('<div class="drawnBox last"></div>').appendTo( dp );
      }

      var drawCSS = {};

      // If drawing is initiated.
      if ( draw ) {

        // Determine the direction.

        // xLeft
        if ( dpLast_data.pageX > pageX ) {
          drawCSS.right = dp.width() - dpLast_data.pageX,
            drawCSS.left = 'auto',
            drawCSS.width = dpLast_data.pageX - pageX;
        }
        // xRight
        else if ( dpLast_data.pageX < pageX ) {
          drawCSS.left = dpLast_data.pageX,
            drawCSS.right = 'auto',
            drawCSS.width = pageX - dpLast_data.pageX;
        }

        // yUp
        if ( dpLast_data.pageY > pageY ) {
          drawCSS.bottom = dp.height() - dpLast_data.pageY,
            drawCSS.top = 'auto',
            drawCSS.height = dpLast_data.pageY - pageY;
        }
        // yDown
        else if ( dpLast_data.pageY < pageY ) {
          drawCSS.top = dpLast_data.pageY,
            drawCSS.bottom = 'auto',
            drawCSS.height = pageY - dpLast_data.pageY;
        }

      }

      if ( !draw && dpLast.length > 0 ) {

        dpLast.css({
          top: pageY,
          left: pageX
        });
      }

      if ( draw ) {
        dpLast.css( drawCSS );
      } 

    }

    if ( e.type === 'mousedown' ) {

      e.preventDefault();
      draw = true;
      dpLast.data({ "pageX": pageX, "pageY": pageY });      

    }
    else if ( e.type === 'mouseup' ) {

      draw = false;
      dpLast.removeClass('last');

    }
  }

  if (drawable) {    
    var dp = $('#drawingArea'),
      draw = false,
      enabled = true;

      dp
       .css({ position: 'relative' })
       .on("mousemove mousedown mouseup", draw_a_box );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/AyaDOVO/6/edit)***

```
$(function(){ // DOM ready

  var drawable = false,
      drawing  = false,
      mS = {},                      // mouse start 
      dBox;

  $('#drawingArea').mousedown(function( e ){
    if(drawable){
      drawing = true;
      mS.x = e.pageX;
      mS.y = e.pageY;
      dBox = $("<div class='drawnBox' />");
      $(this).append(dBox);
    }
  });

  $(document).mousemove(function(e){
    if(drawing && drawable){
      var mPos = {x:e.pageX, y:e.pageY};
      var css = {};
      css.left   = (mPos.x > mS.x) ? mS.x : mPos.x;
      css.top    = (mPos.y > mS.y) ? mS.y : mPos.y;
      css.width  = Math.abs(mPos.x - mS.x);
      css.height = Math.abs(mPos.y - mS.y);
      dBox.css(css);
    }
  }).mouseup(function(e){
    drawing  = false;
  });

  $('.div-tool').click(function(){
    drawable ^= 1;    // TOGGLE
  });  
  $('.select-tool').click(function() {
    drawable = false; // OFF
  });

}); // !DOM ready
```

Note, I've put the .drawnBox CSS from jQ to the CSS.

Comment: How does `drawable ^= 1;` toggle the click event?